# Issue with dynamically rendering inputField from fieldset in Visualforce page

Tags: visualforce, dynamic-visualforce, dynamic-binding

I have a page where inputFields are rendered from a fieldset on Opportunity object.
When I load the page, it loads correctly.
But when any server side action is done and page is re-rendered an error occurs saying 'Invalid field ContractId for Sobject Opportunity'.

I have checked the FLS, it's as expected.

Thing I would like to highlight again, it loads first time without any error.

Comment: Could you post the Visualforce code you are seeing the error with?

Comment: I do not have the code right now. But here's what the code does: iterates using apex:repeat on a list of FieldSetMember, uses an instance of Opportunity object and the inputField is bound with this repeat var which gives field api name... something like this: "{!oppInstance[repeatvar.fieldpath]}"